# Move saved Skyrim game from PS3 to Switch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to move saved Skyrim games from PS3 to the Switch? I saw other questions about moving from PS3 to PC, etc, but nothing about PS3 to switch.

Comment: Welcome to the exchange, Craeft! Has your Nintendo Switch been modded in any way, and are you willing to do that? It'll likely be your only option, if such an option even exists.

Comment: Oh ok. It's my friend's Switch, and she just opened it an hour ago. I don't think she wants to mod it.

Comment: The Switch (and Nintendo in general) is notorious for making saved game backup, copy, and transfer to be extra difficult. [You can transfer between Switch systems](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/guide-how-to-share-games-and-saves-across-nintendo-switch-and-switch-lite), but there is no support for doing it beyond their own platforms (either cloud or transferring to a nearby Switch). I suspect this is simply an extension of what they have already done with 3DS, with the saved games encrypted to the specific device.

Comment: It seems like it is not possible.  If someone wants to write that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can write your own answers. I just don't have any specific information about the switch and don't want to bother with the research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible, especially if the owner isn't willing to mod the Switch.